# Event to track quote changes in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, sales-quote

I want an observer to track changes in Quote like when removing products, updating, adding product from frontend and backend as well. This observer should run after magento native code.

There are many events like below which are executed during quote but I am not sure which observer will be fit for my requirement--

**sales_quote_remove_item**

**sales_quote_add_item**

**sales_quote_product_add_after**

**sales_quote_item_collection_products_after_load**

**checkout_cart_add_product_complete**

**checkout_cart_save_before**

**checkout_cart_save_after**
etc...

Answer (score 1):

The events, you should keep the track of are:

```
sales_quote_add_item
sales_quote_remove_item
```

These events will work for the frontend, as well as the backend. They should help you in tracking Quote changes.